# Remove http:// from $base_url

Tags: emails, uri

I am trying to generate a email address that reads as no-reply@example.com.

Using the global base_url the output is http://example.com.

Is there another global, or some other easy solution, to remove the "http://", so that I get the string example.com?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you're looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Also see [$base_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_path/7.x), [$base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_url/7.x), [$base_root](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_root/7.x)